# Signature mismatch with Set implementation

Tags: module, ocaml, structure

```
module type SET =
sig
  type 'a set
  val member : 'a -> 'a set -> bool
  val subset : 'a set -> 'a set -> bool
end;;

module MySet : SET = struct
  type 'a set = 'a -> bool

  let member element set = set element

  let subset set1 set2 =
    let subset_check elem = member elem set2 in
    member subset_check set1
end
```

```
Lines 8-16, characters 21-3:
Error: Signature mismatch:
Modules do not match:
  sig
    type 'a set = 'a -> bool
    val member : 'a -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b
    val subset : (('a -> 'b) -> 'c) -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'c
  end
is not included in
  SET
Values do not match:
  val subset : (('a -> 'b) -> 'c) -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'c
is not included in
  val subset : 'a set -> 'a set -> bool
```

Can anybody tell why i am getting his error?
and what should be the correct code.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting a signature mismatch error because the type it specifies for the subset function does not match your implementation. A good tip for narrowing down type errors is to annotate types closer to the source of the problem. If you add type annotations to the arguments of `subset` you'll get a more precise error:

```
let subset (set1: 'a set) (set2: 'a set): bool =
  let subset_check elem = member elem set2 in
  member subset_check set1
```

```
Line 15, characters 24-28:
Error: This expression has type 'a set = 'a -> bool
but an expression was expected of type ('a -> bool) -> 'b
The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a -> bool
```

which points to the problem here being that you are passing a `set` to a `subset_check` function that expects an element.

Comment: what i am i supposed to write, could you please write the correct code.. thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to do your homework since that would defeat the purpose of it.

Comment: it's not the homework, it would be great if you can provide the correct code, it will give me a clarity, as i am just in the learning process .

Comment: If so, some context is needed here to understand why you've chosen to implement it this way. It doesn't make much practical sense.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is not possible to implement the `subset` function for sets defined by predicates.

A formal way to see it is that the existence of the function `subset` implies the existence of the function `equal`:

```ml
let equal x y = subset x y && subset y x
```

In your case, the function equal will have type

```
val equal: ('a -> bool) -> ('a -> bool) -> bool
```

and such equality of functions is not decidable.

A maybe more intuitive way to describe the problem is that being able to decide that an element is a member of a set does not imply being able to enumerate the element of the sets. And if one does not know all the elements of the set `s1`, it is not possible to know if `s1` is a subset of `s2` or not.